# Why does println print the value of a referenced object rather than the address of the object

Tags: java, reference

```
String myString="Plz_help";
```

I came to know that 'myString' is not an object but a object reference variable which stores the base address of the actual object. So 'myString' should return an address when i execute

```
System.out.println(myString);
```

but it is returning 'Plz_help' to the output.

```
Myclass obj_ref_var=new Myclass();
```

When I use the same System.out.println(obj_ref_var) for other class which I had created, it is returning the address.

Comment: Please write complete code of MyClass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `System.out.println` on an object reference, system executes `toString()` method defined for the actual object that this reference refers to. For `String` this method returns its value.

Apparently, you haven't defined `toString()` method for your class that's why you get object classname + hashcode.

Answer (score 2):

`println` knows about `String`s, and outputs their contents.

When you pass something other than a `String` into `println`, it implicitly calls that thing's `toString` method. The default `toString` on `Object` returns what you're seeing, which is *not* an address, but rather the name of the class, a `@`, and the [hex version of the object's hash code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

Comment: So its not an address.Thanx. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, `System.out.println` uses the reference to call the object's `toString` method.

As the `toString()` method of string returns the string itself, this is what printed.

But since you haven't override the `toString` method of `MyClass`, it returns the default `toString`, which is classname + hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

When you `System.out.println()` an object, the println method checks if it's null and prints null if it is. If it isn't null, it calls the `toString()` method of the object. The `toString()` method of `String` overrides the `Object.toString()` method, to return itself.

Anyway, `System.out.println()` doesn't print the reference, it prints the object itself. The Object's implementation of toString() returns the class name of the object followed by its hashCode.